# Adverb for “of this”

Tags: meaning

I’ve heard of the adverb, “thereof” meaning “of that.” However I’m looking for an adverb that means “of this.” I’ve looked it up and I keep finding “thereof,” but that doesn’t really fit. I’m trying to say, “an example of this...” and I’ve been saying “of this” a lot and I just want another way to say it for the sake of variety.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is ***hereof***, which per the OED means

> 1. Of this; concerning this.

They mention that it’s the same sort of compound as we see in Danish *heraf*, Swedish *häraf*.

However, I don’t especially recommend it in normal writing, as it sounds quite old-fashioned. It’s not marked archaic or obsolete or anything, but here are a handful of the more recent citations:

> - **1617**   F. Moryson *Itinerary* ii. 206  — The Spaniards, departed..on Tuesday the 16 hereof.
> - **1711**   R. Steele *Spectator* No. 140. ⁋2  — Upon the Receipt hereof.
> - **1870**   F. W. H. Myers *Poems* (1875) 47 —  Thinking hereof I wot not.

Like *thereof*, it sounds like legalese these days.

Comment: "Thereof" has different meanings. It depends on context. Thereof =  relatively, pertinently, thereof, as to, as for, as respects, as regards, regarding, about, concerning, relating to, as relates to, with relation, with reference to, with respect to, with regard to, while speaking of, a propos of